# Binary to hexadecimal conversion in tsql

Tags: sql-server-2005

In CSharp if I do

```
string binary = "10011101";
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToInt32(binary, 2).ToString("X"));
```

I will get the output as 9D. This is the simplest code which I can write in CSharp for converting Binary to Hexadecimal.

Is there any such way to do the same in SQL also(using some inbuilt function if any is available). Is it `fn_varbintohexstr?`

Is there any bitwise operation which will help to do the same conversion.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
select master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@binvalue)
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a built-in function which will convert a stream of bits into hex.

One solution would be to write a CLR function to carry out the conversion using the .Net code you have above.

Below is a T-SQL implementation, which splits the string into individual characters and then converts them to hex. If you have your own numbers table, the CTE can be discarded:

```
DECLARE @vch_string VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @chr_delim CHAR(1)
SET @chr_delim = ','
SET @vch_string = '10011101'

-- replace nums_cte with a join to a numbers table if you have one
-- since it will be far more efficient.
;WITH nums_cte
AS
(
SELECT 1 AS n
UNION ALL
SELECT n+1 FROM nums_cte
WHERE n < LEN(@vch_string)
)

SELECT CAST(SUM(CAST(SUBSTRING(s,n,1) AS INT) * POWER(2,n -1)) AS VARBINARY(1)) AS hexvalue
FROM (SELECT REVERSE(@vch_string) AS s) AS D
JOIN nums_cte
ON n <= LEN(s)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```